# Similarities between company names : compsim module does not work

Tags: python, arrays, database, module

I'm trying to use the module `compsim` in order to get probabilities of matching between company names:

```py
import csv
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Python Scripts/compsim-0.0.3')

from compsim.company_name_similarity import CompanyNameSimilarity

cm = CompanyNameSimilarity()
cm.match_score("Rombus Solutions ltd", "Axia Solutions pvt ltd")
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\compsim-0.0.3-py3.6.egg\compsim\company_name_similarity.py", line 18, in preprocess
return field.encode('utf-8').lower().replace('\n','').replace("'",' ').replace('\r','').replace('/',' ').\

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Please help me, I am stuck.

Thanks !

Comment: Compsim module : https://github.com/asamat/compsim

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the `compsim` module to me. `str.encode()` returns a bytes object, in which you can only replace other bytes objects and not strings.

Replacing bytes works:

```
field = "Rombus"
field.encode('utf-8').replace(b'\n', b'')
```

Omitting `encode` also works:

```
field = "Rombus"
field.replace('\n', '')
```

One solution would be to modify the source code locally. Removing `.encode('utf-8')` should be safe since Python 3 is utf-8-encoded by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your research.